# MapView in Fragment in ViewPager: onMapReady() is never called after calling getMapAsync()

Tags: android, google-maps, android-viewpager

I try to use a map in my app, more precisely in a `ViewPager` page/fragment. What I want is to get data from a google sheet, and then update the map with the pins generated from the google sheet data.

I already have an app that works perfectly, but with an activity and a MapFragment. When I try to transpose it into a `ViewPager` with `MapView` and a fragment, I try to call `getMapAsync()` in the fragment's `onViewCreated`.

However, `onMapReady()` is never called after that. Am I missing something? I've tried to override the fragment's lifecycle methods to insert the `MapView`'s ones, but it didn't change anything.

If anybody has had this kind of problem, help is welcome, I'm letting my code below.

StoreLocatorFragment:

```
private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

private val markers = mutableListOf<ShopMarkerData>()

private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private var lastLocation: Location? = null
private lateinit var lastMarker: ShopMarkerData

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    enovap_mv.getMapAsync(this)

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context!!)
    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
        .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
            lastLocation = location
        }

    [...]

}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    // Function launching the data retrieving on the Google Sheets
}


override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    mMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(context, R.raw.maps_style))
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener {
        if (layout_selected_marker.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            layout_selected_marker.startAnimation(
                AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    context,
                    R.anim.maps_card_out
                )
            )
        }
        layout_selected_marker.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(it.position.latitude, it.position.longitude), 14f))
        for (shop in markers) {
            if (shop.lat == it.position.latitude && shop.lng == it.position.longitude) {
                layout_selected_marker.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                layout_selected_marker.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.maps_card_in))
                lastMarker = shop
                tv_shop_name.text = shop.name
                tv_shop_address.text = shop.street
                tv_shop_city.text = getString(R.string.city_assemble, shop.postcode, shop.city)
                tv_shop_country.text = shop.country
                tv_shop_phone.text = shop.phone
            }
        }
        true
    }
}

private fun getRequestValues(values: List<List<Any>>?) {

    if (values == null)
        return

    for (row in values) {
        val shop = ShopMarkerData("", "", "", "", "", "", "", 0.0, 0.0)
        for (i in row.indices) {
            when (i) {
                0 -> shop.name = row[i] as String
                1 -> shop.street = row[i] as String
                3 -> shop.postcode = row[i] as String
                4 -> shop.city = row[i] as String
                5 -> shop.country = row[i] as String
                6 -> shop.phone = row[i] as String
                7 -> shop.address = row[i] as String
                8 -> shop.lat = (row[i] as String).toDouble()
                9 -> shop.lng = (row[i] as String).toDouble()
            }
        }
        markers.add(shop)
    }

    for (place in markers) {
        val pos = LatLng(place.lat, place.lng)
        val bitmapDescriptor = bitmapDescriptorFromVector(context!!, R.drawable.ic_pin)

        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(pos).title(place.address).icon(bitmapDescriptor))
    }
    mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(lastLocation!!.latitude, lastLocation!!.longitude), 14f))
}
```

XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/enovap_mv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline1"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_selected_marker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape_default"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_shop_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:text="Green and Vape"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_shop_name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_shop_address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                tools:text="23 rue du Roule"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_shop_city"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                tools:text="75001 PARIS"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_shop_country"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                tools:text="France"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_shop_phone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_phone"
                android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="01 40 13 09 57" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_direction"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/layout_address"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/layout_address"
            android:text="Route"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue once in fragment and I apply the following code. I hope it helps you

```
public override fun onResume() {
    mapView.onResume()
    super.onResume()
}

public override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mapView.onPause()
}

public override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    if (mapView != null) {
        mapView.onDestroy()
    }
}

override fun onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory()
    mapView.onLowMemory()
}
```

Comment: I already tried it, it is not working, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(activity.getApplicationContext());
write this line before enovap_mv.getMapAsync(this)

or you can also try
enovap_mv.onResume()
before enovap_mv.getMapAsync(this)
```

Comment: I tried both, none is working, thanks for the suggestion!